# How to launch an external executable on windows in go

Tags: windows, go

I am trying to launch an external executable (msi driver installer) on windows with go. It is referred to with the relative path `bin\launchme.msi`

As of now, I am using the [`commander-cli/cmd`](https://github.com/commander-cli/cmd) library and it is working well with other external executable (though only command line ones).

My command is:

```golang
c := cmd.NewCommand(`bin\launchme.msi`)
c.Execute()
```

The executable is launched but displays the following:

```
An error occurred while writing installation information to disk. 
Check to make sure enough disk space is available."
```

See here:

[image: error screenshot]

What is especially confusing to me is that, as you can see on the screenshot, the msi installer created a `%SystemDrive%` folder in the working directory.
This folder in turn contains a `Program Files` folder and some more subfolders.

Otherwise, if I simply launch the msi installer by double-clicking it, everything is fine, no error occurs.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be, that your .MSI file is using cmd.exe in the background.

If you type `echo %my_env_var%` in cmd.exe, there are two cases what can happen:

- If the environment variable `my_env_var` is defined, the built-in `echo` command of cmd.exe prints it’s value.
- If the environment variable `my_env_var` is not defined, the built-in `echo` command of cmd.exe prints `%my_env_var%` literally.

Every process inherits the environment variables of it’s parent process. If a process is started from the (Windows) File Explorer (`explorer.exe`) or from the (graphical) shell of Windows (also `explorer.exe`), then it inherits the system settings for environment variables.

It seems like your library is dropping some environment variables like `SystemDrive` when starting a new process from the executable `bin\launchme.msi`.

Try to use `import("os/exec")` from the Go standard library https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec .

For more information about environment variable in Microsoft Windows see for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables

Tip:
You can use [Process Explorer (`procexp.exe`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see the environment variables of running processes, by doing this:

- Open Process Explorer, to get a list of running processes
- Right-click on the process you are intrested in, to open the context menu
- In the context menu click on `Preferences`
- In the new window click on the Tab `Environment`.

Comment: It looks like `commander-cli/cmd` drops env vars by default, but [cmd.WithInheritedEnvironment(cmd.EnvVars)](https://github.com/commander-cli/cmd/blob/main/command.go#L155) should pass env vars.

Answer (score 0):

one workaround, for testing, would be to launch that Go program in C:\ as working directory:

```golang
// caputred is the captured output from all executed source code
// fnResult contains the result of the executed function
captured, fnResult := cmd.CaptureStandardOut(func() interface{} {
    c := NewCommand("C:\path\to\bin\launchme.msi", cmd.WithWorkingDir("C:\\")
    err := c.Execute()
    return err
})

// prints "hello"
fmt.Println(captured)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help: now this strange %SystemDrive% folder gets created in C:\

Comment: @squeezeitthroughthekeyhole If you open a cmd, and type `set sys`, you should see the environment variable `SystemDrive=C:`. So try `NewCommand("cmd /C C:\path\to\bin\launchme.msi", cmd.WithWorkingDir("C:\\")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! As Ole pointed out correctly, it was a problem with the library I was using that was dropping environment variables...